# How to insert a unique random integer in SQLite?

Tags: random, sqlite, sql-insert

Let's say I'm saving users in a database and I want each user to have a unique random ID (this isn't actually the case, just a simpler example). When I `INSERT` the user, is there a way to insert a unique random ID?

I know I can easily just do an auto-increment column so that each row would have a unique integer, but I need a random number for this system specifically.

Sample of what my standard insert query for a new user:

`INSERT INTO 'Users' VALUES ('RandomID', 'Bleh', 'Bleh2') (random value here, 1, 2)`

Comment: But how can I determine the unique random number otherwise?

Comment: Do you actually need a _random_ ID, or just a unique but arbitrary one? If the latter, make the first column an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and it will alias the rowid.

Comment: I definitely need a random ID. It has to be random. I'd hate to have to loop through every column and compare a random ID that I generate, then do it again every time the random ID I generate matches an ID that already exists (which is what I'm currently doing, and that's obviously unhealthy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the same and found an interesting answer in [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/random-collisions): use a pre-populated table.

You create before hand a table of n rows with unique random numbers, using any method (for example, by trying to insert random numbers in a UNIQUE field and silently failing when the number isn't unique, until you get the number of rows needed).

Once that table is created you are 100% certain that the numbers in it are unique, and you can simply use them sequentially and discarding them after use (or not).

When using this method you need to have some kind of alert system for when you approach the limit of rows in the pre-populated table, so that you can generate a new set of values anew.

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite has [`random()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random) which returns a random integer. But it may not be unique every time. You can append time stamp or `row_id` with it to get unique random number.

Comment: This might be the best way. It's not exactly what I was hoping for though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this documentation for the C API function `sqlite3_randomness()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/randomness.html), it might be possible to make a table's primary key random by creating a dummy row and forcing it's primary key value to the largest possible ROWID. Any new rows after that should be random.

That said, I don't know that that behavior is contractual or just a current implementation detail. Use at your own risk.